# Strapi nested components not showing up in strapi get API

Tags: strapi, koa, koa2

I have two components. addon and addon_item.
addon again have addon_item as component as one of its field.

One collection named menu_item which have a field as addon_component.

Now when i am running "http://localhost:1337/api/menu-items/1?populate=*" API. I am getting addons in api response but not addon_items inside addon.

In strapi data is there. Attaching strapis content manager API for reference.

[My local API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D8II.jpg)
[Starpi's content manager API's response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4YWT.jpg)

Do i need to enable something?
API's are accessible to authenticated token.
Not sure if components' access needs to be/ can be altered.
But addon component is there in response so confused on why addon_item won't be there.

Thanks in advance.

checked the authorisation for components. Didn't find anything. As in mentioned, addon component is there in response, not sure if i m missing anything for nested components.

Expecting resolution or hints/steps i can take to debug this

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Got the answer after some more research.

```
http://localhost:1337/api/menu-items/1?populate[0]=addons&populate[1]=addons.addon_item
```

Just needed to add params like this to populate.

Before posting the question, I tried:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/menu-items/1?[populate]=*
```

But it didn't work.